# Restlet: How can I retrieve DTO with setting custom MediaType?

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

How can I send GET request for entity with custom `MediaType`?

For example I want to retrieve `MyUserDTO` and set `MediaType` to `application/user+yml`.

For now I have two separated actions. I can retrieve entity:

```
resource.get(MyUserDTO.class);
```

and can retrieve string:

```
resource.get(new MediaType("application", "user+yml");
```

But how to combine them? Or maybe there is some trick to configure `Restlet` to teach him how to work with custom MediaTypes.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you have the right approach but you don't use the right constructor of the class `MediaType` (`new MediaType(name, description)`).

To make your code work, you need to change it to this:

```
resource.get(new MediaType("application/user+yml"));
```

On the server side, you will get this:

```
@Get
public Representation getSomething() {
    System.out.println(">> media types = " +
    getRequest().getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes());
    // Display this: media types = [application/user+yml:1.0]
    (...)
}
```

You can leverage the extension support of Restlet by adding a value within the annotation `Get`. In your case, you need to add a custom extension as described below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public MyApplication() {
        getMetadataService().addExtension(
            "myextension", new MediaType("application/user+yml"));
        (...)
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Now you can use the extension within your server resource:

```
@Get("myextension")
public Representation getSomething() {
    (...)
}
```

This method will be used with the expected media type is `application/user+yml`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry